# Finding a regexp pattern not preceeded by something

Tags: html, regex, tags, negative-lookbehind

I have this following HTML file structure:

```
<table>
   <tr class="heading">
      <td colspan="2">
         <h2 class="groupheader">Public Types</h2> 
         <!-- I don't want that! We're in a table.-->
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>...</tr> 
</table>
<h2 class="groupheader">Detailed Description</h2>
  <!-- I want all that until the next h2-->
  <div class="textblock"><p>Provides the functions to control the generation of a single data log file. </p>
    <h4>Example</h4>
    <div class="fragment"><div class="line">Test <a href="aaa">stuff</a>();</div>
        <div class="line">...</div>     
        <div class="line">...</div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of first result -->

<h2 class="groupheader">Member</h2>
<!-- I want all that until the next h2 or hr-->
<a class="anchor"></a>
<div class="memitem">
<div class="memproto">
      <table class="memname">
        <tr>
          <td class="memname">enum <a class="el" href="...">test</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</div><div class="memdoc">
<hr><!-- End of 2nd result -->
```

And with a Regexp, I need to get all the content between each  titles till the next  title or hr tag, **expect if it's a  in a table**.

So far, I've got all my h2->h2|hr content. It goes like:

```
(?s)(<h2 class="groupheader">.*?)(<h2|<hr)
```

How can I skip the content under the H2 that is contained in the table? I've tried noodling with a negative look behind but I'm not getting anywhere.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: It seems like you've got some typos that prevent me from understanding the question, could you fix them? Maybe provide some sample data and sample output?

Comment: what you need to get exactly, did not understand, add an example please and how it fails

Comment: I've tried to clarify my problem. Hope it's better!

Comment: This is going to be super ugly, if not outright impossible with regex alone. It would be better for you to use a DOM parser

Comment: would help if you mention what language/program you are using the regex for. This is basically impossible with regex alone without *variable width*  negative lookbehind, which is not supported for a lot of languages/programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE THAT HTML SHOULD BE PARSED WITH AN APPROPRIATE PARSER**

Now, since we are left with just HTML-looking input, and a task

> to get all the content between each titles till the next title or hr tag, expect if it's a in a table

let me show how it could be done.

You can obtain the substrings you need with the help of a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) `((?:(?!<\/table|<h2|<hr)(?:<table\b[^<]*>.*?<\/table>|.))*)` (that matches any symbol that is not starting any of the alternatives in the negative lookahead before it - thus, keeping the match within the `<table>` boundaries - and also matching the inner tables) with a positive lookahead at the end:

```
(?s)<h2 class="groupheader">[^<]*<\/h2>\s*((?:(?!<\/table|<h2|<hr)(?:<table\b[^<]*>.*?<\/table>|.))*)(?=<h2|<hr)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lU5tG6/3).

Note that instead of `h2` you can use `h\d+` to support any level of `h`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, that takes care of of the h2 section that's in a table, but I lost a h2 that isnt in a table. I've updated my sample to add a case. It's rough...

Comment: Please check my update. It is ugly, but it should work if the table tags are not misplaced.